# AAOS Heads-up notifications throttling and suppression - What is that?

Tags: android, android-automotive

In Android Automotive 14 release notes there is one item:

Heads-up notifications (HUN) throttling and suppression. Developed an OEM-configurable mechanism to prevent the overlapping on HUNs and the sending of HUNs to drivers at inopportune times.

But what exactly is that mechanism? Where I can see the logic of it, some related code maybe?

I looked at
https://developer.android.com/training/cars/notifications
and
https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/hmi/notifications/hun
but can't find anything about throttling and suppression there

Comment: Since the edit queue is full and I can't add it to the question here's a link to [the release notes](https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/start/releases/u_udc_release) for anyone else who happens upon this question. I don't have a definitive answer myself but my hunch is that since it's part of the system UI this may not be an API that's available to developers